# Abuse filter doesn't work at all

Tags: mediawiki

I have just installed the abuse filter extension:

```
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter
```

and imported this filter and many other:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:AbuseFilter/344
```

but for some reason none of them works. By that I mean when I try to (example) blank a page I get no warning nor does it prevent me from doing that even though it should according to the settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the filter code:

```
article_namespace == 0 &
!"confirmed" in user_groups &
new_size <12 &
old_size > 300 &
!user_name in article_recent_contributors
```

there are 2 safeguards here to prevent false positives: editor must not be [autoconfirmed](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Autoconfirmed) and must not be among page's latest contributors. On your wiki, you're 99% likely to pass both these checks so the filter doesn't react to your edits, exactly  as it was intended.